# SetOptions accepting one number variable, rejecting another number variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Gmaps APIV3 accepts my `x` variable, but rejects my `weight` variable, although both are numbers. Whats going on here?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        var zoomLevel = map.getZoom(); //something between 18-12
        var weight =  zoomLevel - 5;
        var x = 3;
        console.log(typeof(x)); // number 
        console.log(typeof(weight)); //number
        $.each(paths, function(i, path){
            path.setOptions({strokeWeight: x}); //works
         // path.setOptions({strokeWeight: weight}); //doesn't work
        })
    });
```

Added javascript as a tag because I am unsure of whether this is strictly Gmaps related or a language thing I'm unaware of. Remove it if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can it be that `zoomLevel` sometimes has not the expected value(18-12) and is <6 ? If yes, `weight` would be <=0 what is an illegal value.

Assign at least 1:

```
var weight =  Math.max(1,zoomLevel - 5);
```

With a zoomLevel >5 your script works for me.